# Calling the callback function on successful authorization

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to developing applications with reactive-native. I'm trying to make a transition with successful authorization to the next application scene. Here is my code

```
login = () => {
   firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password
   ).then((userData) => {
       var uid = userData.uid;
       localStorage.save('uidKey', uid)
       console.log('uidKey');
       // transition
     }
   ).catch((error) => {
     AlertIOS.alert(
      'Login Failed!',
      'Please try again'
     );
   }); }); }
```

I know how to trigger a transition by pressing the button. By adding this line of code

```
onPress={() => Actions.root()}>
```

But I have no idea how to call this function from a callback. In the string //transition

Be so kind, help me

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import Actions and then fire off the same transition:

```
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
...
login = () => {
    firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password
    ).then((userData) => {
            var uid = userData.uid;
            localStorage.save('uidKey', uid)
            console.log('uidKey');
            // transition
            Actions.root()
        }
    ).catch((error) => {
        AlertIOS.alert(
            'Login Failed!',
            'Please try again'
        );
    }); }); }
```

Comment: I imported this module import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'; I can do this only by pressing the button. But i need to call the function out of the callback.

Comment: What is wrong with using ```Actions.root()``` there? Did it fail?

Comment: I was helped by your decision! :) I'm sorry, I did not see at once a string "Actions.root()" . Thank you so much!